# Google Script Editor getRange takes 10 seconds on 1 column, ~0 on another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a budgeting spreadsheet that aggregates data from 10+ sheets into one master sheet. One of the calls is `sheet.getRange(1, 1, max_rows);` (or something close to that). That call takes approximately 10 seconds on the first column, but closer to 0 seconds on other columns. Each of those calls is on the same size sheet (about 75 rows).

I run this call on each sheet, so while 10 seconds is ok once, 100+ seconds is a long runtime!

Here is a snippet of the code. I've tried both `set 1` and `set 2`, to the same result. `ss` and `cities` are set earlier in the script.

```
var city_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(cities[i]);
var city_rows = city_sheet.getMaxRows();

// set one
var cat_range = city_sheet.getRange(1,1,city_rows).getValues(); // this one takes 10 seconds
var subcat_range = city_sheet.getRange(1,2,city_rows).getValues(); // ~0 sec
var value_range = city_sheet.getRange(1,4,city_rows).getValues(); // ~0 sec

// set two
var city_data = city_sheet.getRange(1, 1, city_rows, 4); // this one takes about 10 seconds
```

I then loop through the data in the range. Any thoughts as to how to speed this up?

Here's a gist of the whole script: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6a8985c9ea5e553182e

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use `getMaxRows();`  I'd use `getLastRow()`.  `getLastRow()` will find the last row of data.  `getMaxRows();` can return lots of rows with nothing in them.  If that doesn't help, then I'd be curious to know what is in column A?

Comment: Well that worked! 2 seconds for the entire script. Make it an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the line:

```
var city_rows = city_sheet.getMaxRows();
```

to:

```
var city_rows = city_sheet.getLastRow();
```

`getLastRow()` will find the last row of data. `getMaxRows()` can return lots of rows with nothing in them.

For example.  If you have lots of formulas copied down in a column.